# Matlab: how to rename a sub-field

Tags: matlab

Let me describe the question in this way. I have a .mat file, and if I open it, it contains a 1x10 struct data. In each data, it has a 1x5 struct (or field) called res. In res, it has a 1x1 struct (or field) called, let's say, foo. Thus, I have ixj copies of data(i).res(j).foo .

Is there anyway I can change the name of this foo? say I want all data(i).res(j).foo to become data(i).res(j).bar

I did search on the internet, and tried a few ways (add field and delete, create a temp field, use cell2field or fieldtofile, etc.) and all of them didn't work. The most frequent returned error is "Subscripted Assignment between dissimilar structures."

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you copy it to the new name, then trim the previous one?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself clear. Please see below, you will know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks caoy and NotLikeThat. I finally came to an conclusion.

```
data2 = data
for i=1:10
    for j = 1:5
        data(i).res(j).bar = data2(i).res(j).foo;
    end
    data(i).res = rmfield(data(i).res, 'foo');
end
```

I probably need to removed i, j, and data2 after running this script.

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is probably by looping over data twice, the first pass creating a new field bar for each subfield like `data(i).res(j).bar=data(i).res(j).foo`, then the second pass deletes the old fields like `data(i).res(j) = rmfield(data(i).res(j),'foo')`.

Comment: You could lose the inner loop using the power of lists: `[data(i).res.bar] = data(i).res.foo;`. `rmfield` works on struct arrays so wouldn't need the inner loop either.

Comment: Thanks Notlikethat, I tried `data(i).res = rmfield(data(i).res,'foo')`, and it worked. Unfortunately `data(i).res(j) = rmfield(data(i).res(j),'foo')` will not work, complaining `Subscripted Assignment between dissimilar structures.`